# If $S(n)$ is an odd integer, what is the sum of all possible $\frac1n?$

Tags: number-theory, integers, prime-factorization, multiplicative-function

If $n$  is a positive integer, let $S(n)$ be the sum of all the positive divisors of $n$.

If $S(n)$ is an odd integer, what is the sum of all possible $\frac1n?$

The function $S$ is multiplicative and so, if we have the prime factorisation $n = p_1^{a(1)}p_2^{a(2)} \cdots p_m^{a(m)}$, where $p_1,p_2,...,p_m$ are distinct primes, then how will I continue to solve this?

Comment: By stating a problem in the form of an "assignment", without indicating how well you have digested the problem yourself, you put your Readers at a disadvantage, having to resort to guesswork as to what response would be helpful.  Please add your own thoughts, such as what makes the problem interesting or important to you, or what difficulty was encountered when you tried a specific approach to a solution.  Often sharing a partial result, observation, or calculation of an illustrative example will go a long way to persuading Readers a certain response will be useful to you.

Comment: The answer is ${\pi}^2/4$.

Comment: @JohnChessant $\pi^2/4 \approx 2.4674$ right?

Comment: @XX: Yes. Also, great job on figuring out the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** The divisors of $p_i^{a(i)}$ are $1, p_i, p_i^2,...,p_i^{a(i)}$. Their sum is.....

Answer (score 3):

> The function $S$ is multiplicative and so, if we have the
>   prime factorisation $n = p_1^{a(1)}p_2^{a(2)} \cdots
> > p_m^{a(m)}$, where $p_1,p_2,...,p_m$ are distinct primes.

Continuing what I said

$ S(n) \; = \; \prod_{k=1}^m S\big(p_k^{a(k)}\big) \; = \; \prod_{k=1}^m \big(1 + p_k + p_k^2 + \cdots + p_k^{a(k)}\big) $

Note that $S(2^n) = 2^{n+1}-1$ is odd for all $n \ge 1$, while $S(p^n)$ is odd precisely when $n$ is even for any odd prime $p$.

If $S(n)$ is to be odd, we must have $S\big(p_k^{a(k)}\big)$ odd for all $k$, and hence the index of any odd prime factor of $n$ must be even. Thus the set of numbers $n$ for which $S(n)$ is odd is the set of perfect squares, together with the set of twice the perfect squares. Thus we need to evaluate

$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}+ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n^2} \; = \; \tfrac32\zeta(2) \; = \; \boxed{\tfrac14\pi^2} $

Answer (score 1):

$S(n)$ is multiplicative, so $S(n) = \prod_{i=1}^m S(p_i^{a_i})$. If any of the $S(p_i^{a_i})$ are even, the whole product will be even. So what is the condition on $S(p^a)$ being even for some prime $p$ and natural number $a$? What does that tell you about the set of numbers $n$ for which $S(n)$ is odd?

Once you've figured this out, you're going to need to sum the series. You'll want to factor out a geometric series involving powers of $2$, and you'll need to use the fact that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^{-2}  = \pi^2/6$.